# how to show id of a button using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Here it is demo of my code. I just want to show Id of button while it is saying undefined

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/2/)

Code:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var ID = $(this).id;
    alert(ID);

});
```

Comment: Seriously, didn't you saw the thousand of thousand examples about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and you will get button id-

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {        
    alert(this.id);        
});
```

second method-

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
  alert(this.id); 
)};
```

After Update - 
[Please Try](http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/18/)

Comment: Is `var $this = $(this);` just to make the code look nice? Or is it to keep the jQuery people happy?

Comment: @Bojangles, no... this is why he has `debugger`!

Comment: not working $this = $(this) but you used this instead of $this

Comment: I didn't understand what you really want, but please see updated "jsfiddle".

Comment: In my project id and name on this anchor is dynamic so i can not use #id and something. I have to do it with help of javascript function @Jay

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the DOM native functions and properties:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);    
});
```

If you decided you want to use jQuery for the overkill:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: AFAIK `.prop()` is preferred over `.attr()` is it not? They do pretty much the same thing so I'm just nitpicking

Comment: @Bojangles, for `id` it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it a little mixed up - you need to be using `this.id`. There is no `id` "method" in jQuery, however getting it via. `.attr('id')` is possible (although there's no real need for that).

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$(".a").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/8/

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1

Use [`$.prop()`](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/prop/&ei=nyTpUbCxJYPYPZiWgKAC&usg=AFQjCNHaMBB-3221pUloi4_sHJpwg7mWnA&sig2=fwvVmOJ1l_hXU6dlNs0-GA&bvm=bv.49478099,d.ZWU).

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).prop("id"));
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/7/)

---

### Approach 2(recommended)

Use `this.id`.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/9/)

Comment: Why not just `this.id`?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, because it's jQuery and you have to use it, the more the better!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr(attribute)`.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(ID);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/11/

Comment: No one downvoted you, though read your code again, what are you doing with `$this`? hint: nothing.

Comment: Okay - I get it... Was a bit overhasty correcting the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

The right code is the following :

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(ID);
});
```

Have a look to the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

You will get the "id" attribute of the element.

Answer (score 0):

It Should be

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
var ID = $(this).attr('id');
alert(ID);

 });
```

Here is Updated Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/vN88X/3/